# Potential Leak of an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am facing Potential leak of an object allocated. So how can I release my custom class object in loop . I am enclosing my code below herewith.

```
- (ProfileClass *) getUserProfile
```

{

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Profile"];
NSLog(@"query %@",query);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MOFAdb.sqlite"];
ProfileClass *profile = nil;
// Open the database. The database was prepared outside the application.
if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    sqlite3_stmt *Statement1;
    //int i=0;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &Statement1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        //int returnValue = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &Statement1, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(Statement1) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            // The second parameter indicates the column index into the result set.

            NSString *userName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(Statement1, 0)];
            NSString *userEmail = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(Statement1, 1)];
            NSString *phoneNum = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(Statement1, 2)];
            //int phone = sqlite3_column_int(Statement1, 2);
            //NSLog(@"%d",phone);

            //RecipeClass *rc = [[RecipeClass alloc] getRecipe:recipeName withRecipeIng:recipeIng withRecipeInst:recipeInstru withRecipeTips:recipeTips withRecipeDesc:recipeDesc];

            if (profile) 
                [profile release];

            profile = [[ProfileClass alloc] getProfileInfo:userName withEmail:userEmail withPhone:phoneNum];

            //NSLog(@"%@",fact);
            //NSLog(@"%d",i);
            //i++;      

        }
    }

    //Release the select statement memory.
    sqlite3_finalize(Statement1);
    //}
}
else {
    // Even though the open failed, call close to properly clean up resources.
    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    // Additional error handling, as appropriate...
}

return profile;
```

}

If I autorelease my profile = [[[ProfileClass alloc] getProfileInfo:userName withEmail:userEmail withPhone:phoneNum] autorelease]; so my application crashes later. So I m release on if check but build and Analyze shows it as a warning.

Comment: Er, do you have an `init` call anywhere?

Comment: You need to post the code of `getProfileInfo:withEmail:withPhone:`.

Comment: As you always start with this ProfileClass *profile = nil; following code will never execut  if (profile) 
                [profile release];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also autorelease like that:

return [profile autorelease];

and retain the object of ProfileClass where you used it,

Ex-  ProfileClass *objProfile=[[database getUserProfile] retain];

and release objProfile when you used it.

Comment: but isnt it same as mine return [[profile autorelease] retain]; ??

Comment: no it is not same because if you retain any object that mean you are the owner of that objects. only you can released it.so you can not release it in other class.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do:

```
return [profile autorelease];
```

And there is no need for the

```
if (profile)
```

check. Just `release` unconditionally. If `profile` is nil, it won't have any negative effect.

---

FWIW: I don't quite understand what your `getProfile:etc...` method does. I assume it is an initializer and nothing more (like the many `initXYZ:` methods in Cocoa). If so, you should probably call it `initWithUserName:email:phone:` to go with the convention. Could you post the method?

Comment: @user366584 just b/c your error went away does not mean that you solved it. Read memory management before giving your advice. What you did with [[mission autorelease] retain]; is wrong. You retain an object that you are autoreleasing. What's the reason behind it. It seams to me that you were shooting blind to solve it just by typing whatever relates to memory management.

Comment: @user366584: Cyprian is right. "It works" doesn't mean what you do is correct. In this case, it doesn't make sense. And what is `mission`?

Comment: sorry there is another Class name Mission so mission is same instance variable as profile

Answer (score 0):

using an array you can solve this issue before calling this method

```
NSMutableArray *ProfileArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[ClassObj getUserProfile]];
ProfileClass *profileObj=[[ProfileArray objectAtIndex:0] retain];
[ProfileArray release];
// now you can use profile object anywhere... I hope memory issue is also solved



- (NSMutableArray *) getUserProfile

{
    NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Profile"];
NSLog(@"query %@",query);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MOFAdb.sqlite"];
ProfileClass *profile = nil;
// Open the database. The database was prepared outside the application.
if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    sqlite3_stmt *Statement1;
    //int i=0;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &Statement1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        //int returnValue = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &Statement1, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(Statement1) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            // The second parameter indicates the column index into the result set.

            NSString *userName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(Statement1, 0)];
            NSString *userEmail = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(Statement1, 1)];
            NSString *phoneNum = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(Statement1, 2)];
            //int phone = sqlite3_column_int(Statement1, 2);
            //NSLog(@"%d",phone);

            //RecipeClass *rc = [[RecipeClass alloc] getRecipe:recipeName withRecipeIng:recipeIng withRecipeInst:recipeInstru withRecipeTips:recipeTips withRecipeDesc:recipeDesc];

            if (profile) 
                [profile release];

            profile = [[ProfileClass alloc] getProfileInfo:userName withEmail:userEmail withPhone:phoneNum];
       [array addObject:profile];
       [profile release];


        }
    }

    //Release the select statement memory.
    sqlite3_finalize(Statement1);
    //}
}
else {
    // Even though the open failed, call close to properly clean up resources.
    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    // Additional error handling, as appropriate...
}

return [array autorelease]; 

}
```

I hope it will be helpful to you
cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your method: `- (ProfileClass *) getUserProfile` is not an instance method or a copy you should return an object that is autoreleased. But you should do it on the last line, since you have a if/else structure and if you only autorelease it on line `profile = [[[ProfileClass alloc] getProfileInfo:userName withEmail:userEmail withPhone:phoneNum] autorelease];` it will not get autoreleased if it fails the if statement and goes to else. So just do this:

```
return [profile autorelease];
```

Comment: FWIW, it is an instance method, as it operates on a single, allocated instance. It is probably just an initializer with the wrong name.

Comment: @Cyprian it is crashing so thats why I suggested a solution in above comments, but it is not proper memory management